# CollectionView fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to figure out what the issue is in this code for it to throw an index out of range error. However, I am unable to understand where the issue is.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class MenuViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"
    let headerId = "headerId"

    var itemCategories: [MenuItemCategory]?
    var menuItem: [MenuItem]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mooyahLabelLogo"))

        collectionView?.register(MenuViewControllerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.register(MenuViewControllerHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)

        MenuItemCategory.fetchMenuItems { (itemCategories) in
            self.itemCategories = itemCategories
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        if let count = itemCategories?.count {
            print("Number of Sections: \(count)")
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! MenuViewControllerHeader

        if let categoryName = itemCategories?[indexPath.section].name {
            header.categoryNameLabel.text = categoryName
        }

        return header
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 44)

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if let count = itemCategories?[section].items?.count {
            print("Number of Items in Section: \(count)")
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuViewControllerCell

        if let category = itemCategories?[indexPath.item] {
            print("Section: \(category.name!)")
            if let itemsCount = category.items?.count {

                for i in 0..<itemsCount {
                    print("Item: \(category.items?[i].name ?? "")")
                    cell.itemNameLabel.text = category.items?[i].name ?? ""
                    cell.itemDescriptionLabel.text = category.items?[i].desc ?? ""

                    if let price = category.items?[i].price {
                        cell.itemPriceLabel.text = "AED \(price)"
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 85)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Here is the debugger print where it shows that my number of sections are correct as well as the number of items in section is correct. I am not sure where the issue arises from?

[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUivN.png)

Comment: Maybe not related but it is nonsensical to declare a data source array of a concrete collection view controller as optional. You can avoid a lot of optional bindings / optional chainings and the code is much better readable.

Comment: @oalansari82 it's hard to test your code better put breakpoint and check flow.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have and this line what causes the error 'if let category = itemCategories?[indexPath.item]'

Comment: `for i in 0..<itemsCount` Why is there a for loop in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`? Seems weird. I'd remove it, and instead `let i = indexPath.row` (or replace all the `i` with `indexPath.row` in that part of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
Shouldn't this line be

```
if let category = itemCategories?[indexPath.section] { .... }
```

Not

```
if let category = itemCategories?[indexPath.item] { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a `guard` to make sure that your items are available like this

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuViewControllerCell

guard let itemCategories = itemCategories, itemCategories.indices.contains(indexPath.item), let items = category.items else {
    return cell
}
if let category = itemCategories[indexPath.item] {
    print("Section: \(category.name!)")

    if let itemsCount = items.count {

        for i in 0..<itemsCount {
            if items.indices.contains(i) {
                print("Item: \(items[i].name ?? "")")
                cell.itemNameLabel.text = items[i].name ?? ""
                cell.itemDescriptionLabel.text = items[i].desc ?? ""

                if let price = category.items?[i].price {
                    cell.itemPriceLabel.text = "AED \(price)"
                }

            }
        }

    }

}

return cell

}
```